# Center the sublist

Tags: jquery, css

Two problems:
First: How can i center right under "List" both items named as class "one"?
Second: How can i center right under "One" and "Two" Items1-3?

I've tried various options, none worked. This is what i got:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
{
    $(".main ul").hide();
    $(".main").click(function() 
 {
        $(".main ul").slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

```css
.main, .one, .two
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.main
{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}

.one, .two
{
    cursor: default;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="main"><h3>List</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="one">One</li>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="two">Item 1</li>
                                        <li class="two">Item 2</li>
                                        <li class="two">Item 3</li>
                                    </ul>
                                <li class="one">Two</li>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="two">Item 1</li>
                                        <li class="two">Item 2</li>
                                        <li class="two">Item 3</li>
                                    </ul>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of what you're trying to achieve is a little vague, but hopfully this is something close.

Firstly, you need to amend your HTML to make it valid. Only `li` elements may be direct descendants of `ul`, so the child `ul` elements need to be contained. Also, the CSS styling of the `.one` elements meant they were displayed side-by-side, instead of underneath each other. Try this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".main ul").hide();
  $(".main").click(function() {
    $(".main ul").slideToggle(200);
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.two {
  cursor: default;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="main">
    <h3>List</h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="one">One
        <ul>
          <li class="two">Item 1</li>
          <li class="two">Item 2</li>
          <li class="two">Item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="one">Two
        <ul>
          <li class="two">Item 1</li>
          <li class="two">Item 2</li>
          <li class="two">Item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard formatting would do this automatically once the HTML issues have been addressed.

Your HTML structure looks a little odd...you are closing the `li` before opening the submenu `ul`.

The centering can then be accomplished by `text-align:center1

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".main ul").hide();
  $(".main").click(function() {
    $(".main ul").slideToggle(200);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="main">
    <h3>List</h3>

    <ul>
      <li class="one">One
        <ul>
          <li class="two">Item 1</li>
          <li class="two">Item 2</li>
          <li class="two">Item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="one">Two
        <ul>
          <li class="two">Item 1</li>
          <li class="two">Item 2</li>
          <li class="two">Item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```